# Accessibility feature for special characters iOS

Tags: ios, accessibility

I am new to accessibility feature. The problem in my application is that some special characters(. -) are not spoken by the application correctly for example

-0.7 is spelt as 7

Comment: Is this just text in a UILabel or have you set an explicit accessibilityLabel yourself?

Comment: I have set accessibility enabled check box to yes from xib.The value is coming from web service as -0.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a number formatter and the "spell out" style to create a more suitable accessibilityLabel for those strings. VoiceOver will then read this string for that label but it's not visible in the UI somewhere.

```
NSNumber *number = @(-0.7);
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSString *spelledOutNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

// set that as the accessibility label to be read instead of the number
yourLabel.accessibilityLabel = spelledOutNumber;
```

That would also give you a solution that works well with different locales (some sample output below):

```
en_US -> minus zero point seven
de_DE -> minus null Komma sieben
fr_FR -> moins zéro virgule sept
ja_JP -> マイナス〇・七
es_ES -> menos cero coma siete
ru_RU -> минус ноль запятая семь
sv_SE -> minus noll komma sju
```

Comment: @user2814546 is the data from the web service a string? if you put a breakpoint, what is the formatted spelledOutNumber for you? how are you verifying what VoiceOver reads (on a real device I hope)?

Comment: Formatted spelledoutNumber is coming proper 20.25(Twenty point two five) but on real device its speaking Two Zero  Two Five

Comment: I am facing again similar issue with email id some.example@company.com is not spelled correctly

Comment: Verify the Punctuation settings for voiceOver - set it to at least "some punctuation". When it is set to "no punctuation" the read out will omit the punctuations and read it out as "some example company com". This can be set with the Rotor